# How to fix error in radaeePDF xamarin setup (CS0246)?

Tags: c#, pdf, xamarin, visual-studio-2022, cs0246

I was following the [setup instructions](https://www.radaeepdf.com/support/knowledge-base?view=kb&kbartid=80) to add [radaee xamarin module](https://github.com/RadaeePDF-Jugaad/RadaeePDF-Xamarin) into a xamarin proyect. I followed the instructions step by step until step 9 just after adding the AndroidManifest.xml lines and trying to do step 10 where you declare the RadaeePDF in the c# code. There i've gotten a CS0246 "The type or namespace name 'type/namespace' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" Any idea how to solve this? I've scoured around but found no solution to this particular problem.

[Radaee is added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIAUp.png)

[Is on the proyect dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uepqm.png)

[Is on the references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0P8U.png)

[I added the xml lines. The only thing I can note here is that the aplication label is not com.radaee.reader, but it shouldn' matter in this case, like the second changes to .util and should work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ie51C.png)

```
<application android:label="name.Android" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:theme="@style/MainTheme" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
        
<activity android:name="com.radaee.reader.PDFViewAct" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>

<activity android:name="com.radaee.util.PopupEditAct" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"/>
        
</application>
```

[But then it doen't register, nor the Global to do the init or the Radaee itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Fo9n.png)

Error:

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'RadaeePDFManager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  name.Android C:\Users\usr\Source\Repos\name\name.Android\MainActivity.cs    33  Active
```

Line 33 is:

```
RadaeePDFManager mPdfManager = new RadaeePDFManager();
```

Im on Visual studio 2022. The min sdk is 19 the target sdk 32.

Comment: Please do not post code or errors as images